# What are the prior arts of US20130128027 A1?

Tags: prior-art-request, us20130128027

Help kill bad patent application "Image Processing Apparatus And Image Processing Method" by providing evidence of prior art.

Publication number  US20130128027 A1
Publication type    Application
Application number  US 13/653,469
Publication date    May 23, 2013
Filing date Oct 17, 2012
Priority date   Nov 18, 2011
Also published as   CN103124358A, EP2595375A1
Inventors   Masaaki Katsurada, Keisuke Nagoshi
Original Assignee   Keyence Corporation

> CLAIM 1. An image processing apparatus, comprising:
>   an imaging unit having
>
> an imaging element for imaging an inspection object; and
>
> an image processing unit for executing image processing on image data captured by the imaging unit, wherein
>   the imaging unit converts a color image imaged by the imaging element to an HDR image based on a conversion characteristic for expanding a dynamic range, to output the HDR image, and
>
> the image processing unit includes
>
> an inverse conversion portion for inversely converting color component values with respect to each pixel of the HDR image, outputted from the imaging unit, based on the conversion characteristic,
>
> a calculation portion for calculating brightness and a ratio of the color component values with respect to each pixel, from the inversely converted color component values, and
>
> a post-correction HDR image generating portion for converting the calculated brightness based on the conversion characteristic, to generate a post-correction HDR image based on a ratio of the converted brightness and the calculated color component values.